# WidgetKit won't request a new timeline at the end

Tags: ios, ios14, widgetkit

When I run the code snippet below, WidgetKit is supposed to request a new timeline at the end of each minute according to the Apple's documentation.

```
Code Block 
let currentDate = Date()
let futureDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 1, to: currentDate)!
let timeline = Timeline(entries: [
      Entry(date: currentDate, number: Int.random(in: 0...10))], policy: .after(futureDate))
completion(timeline)
```

But it just works once and nothing happens afterward as if it has been set to `.never`. I am trying it on iOS 14 Beta 2.

Comment: Please refer my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62873336/ios-widgetkit-widget-not-getting-updated-even-when-userdefaults-are-synchroniz

Comment: My widget requests new timelines, but only for a few hours after it's run. Then it just completely stops. If I add a new widget, that one will work for a while, but the original widget never updates (even if I call reloadAllTimelines from inside the main app).

Answer (score 0):

That's because your updates are too aggressive.
Change it to 15 minutes and it will work